# How to change the background image IBM mobile anywhere app in login page

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am looking to re-design the Login  page. I need to add a new background image. Let me know where should I be copying  this image into the project and where should I be specifying the image reference. I see the change made directly into Login.html are not reflecting in the output.

Comment: Voting this down because we don't have enough information to help you. Please edit your question and provide more details on your setup and your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two logos in Maximo Anywhere, ibmLogoDark.png and ibmLogoLight.png (for the light and dark backgounds). You will need to obtain suitable replacement (transparent backgound) logo gifs or png files from your customer, of an equivalent size.

The IBM logo image files are in:
\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\common\js\platform\ui\control\images\mdpi
and also in:
\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\common\idx\mobile\themes\common\idx\images

So that is where I put copies of my customers replacement logos.

You'll want to give them different names from the IBM logos just so they don't get overwritten so easily. There are 4 CSS files you need to update to the new name:

about.css, launch.css and login.css in:
\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\common\idx\mobile\themes\common\idx
and mdpi.css in
\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\common\js\platform\ui\control\css

There are also two app.xml files you need to update to point to the new names. One in each of:
\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\platform-artifacts\dialog
and
\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\platform-artifacts\login

Then rebuild and you're done. Oh, and make sure you clear your browser cache (or use incognito mode) to test.